# Recurrent neural networks for Time Series with Multiple Variables - TensorFlow

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, reshape

I'm using previous demand to predict future demand, using `3 variables`, but whenever I run the code my `Y axis` shows error

If I use only one variable on the `Y axis` separately it has no error.

**Example:**

```
demandaY = bike_data[['cnt']]
n_steps = 20

for time_step in range(1, n_steps+1):
    demandaY['cnt'+str(time_step)] = demandaY[['cnt']].shift(-time_step).values

y = demandaY.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = np.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], n_steps, 1))
```

**DATASET**

[image]

**SCRIPT**

```
features = ['cnt','temp','hum']
demanda = bike_data[features]
n_steps = 20

for var_col in features:
    for time_step in range(1, n_steps+1):
        demanda[var_col+str(time_step)] = demanda[[var_col]].shift(-time_step).values

demanda.dropna(inplace=True)
demanda.head()

n_var = len(features)
columns = list(filter(lambda col: not(col.endswith("%d" % n_steps)), demanda.columns))

X = demanda[columns].iloc[:, :(n_steps*n_var)].values
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], n_steps, n_var))

y = demanda.iloc[:, 0].values
y = np.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], n_steps, 1))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 17379 into shape (17379,20,1)
```

**GitHub:** [repository](https://github.com/matheusfacure/Tutoriais-de-AM/blob/master/Redes%20Neurais%20Artificiais/rnn_ts_tutorial.ipynb)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement a sliding window across your timeseries data, is that right? If so I can post an answer that illustrates how to create a sliding window using NumPy that gives you the feature and targets that you need?

Comment: That, exactly what I want to do, if you can provide me will help!!

Comment: your last line has an error. `y` is an array of shape `17379,1` which means it has total of 17379 elements and your new shape has number of elements as 17379x20x1 , so thats why it throws an error. Anyway in [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) tutorial there is a function `create_dataset()`which builds sliding windowed data.

Comment: @LuisHenrique , For `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 17379 into shape (17379,20,1)`, you can use **np.stack(X)** and then for validation you can print **np.shape**. That will help you to move forward

Comment: I agree to what Mr. @MuhammadUsman said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear if the OP still wants the answer but I will post the answer I linked in the comment with a few modifications.

Timeseries datasets can be of different types, lets consider a dataset which has `X` as features and `Y` as labels. Depending on the problem `Y` might be a sample from `X` shifted in time or can also be another target variable you want to predict.

```
def create_dataset(X,Y, look_back=10, label_lag = -1, stride = 1):

    dataX, dataY = [], []

    for i in range(0,(len(X)-look_back + 1),stride):
        a = X[i:(i+look_back)]
        dataX.append(a)
        b = Y[i + look_back + label_lag]
        dataY.append(b)
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

print(features.values.shape,labels.shape)
#(619,4), (619,1)

x,y = create_dataset(X=features.values,Y=labels.values,look_back=10,stride=1)
(x.shape,y.shape)
#(610, 10, 4), (610, 1)
```

Use of other parameters :

1. `label_lag` : if `X` samples are at time `t`, `Y` samples will be at time `t+label_lag`. The default value will put both `X` and `Y`at same index `t`.

the indices of 1st sample of `X` and `Y`:

```
if label_lag is -1:
np.where(x[1,-1]==features.values)[0],np.where(y[1] == labels.values)[0]
#(10,10,10,10), (10)

if label_lag is 0:
np.where(x[1,-1]==features.values)[0],np.where(y[1] == labels.values)[0]
#(10,10,10,10), (11)
```

2. `look_back`: this is the number of samples of past history of your dataset from your current timestep `t`. look_back of 10 means there will be samples from `t-10 to t` in one single sample.
3. `stride` : the index gap between two consecutive samples. When `stride=2`,  If 1st sample of `X` has rows from index `0 to 10` then 2nd sample will have rows from the index `2 to 12`.

Furthermore, you can also have a lookback in `Y` depending on your current problem and `Y` can also be multi-dimensional. In that case the change is only this `b=Y[i:(i+look_back+label_lag)]`.

The same functionality can be achieved by `TimeseriesGenerator` from `keras`.

```
TimeseriesGenerator(features.values,labels.values,length=10,batch_size=64,stride=1)
```

where `length` is same as `look_back`. By default there is a gap in `features` and `labels` by 1, i.e. a sample in `X` will be from `t-10 to t` and corresponding sample in `Y` will be at index `t+1`. If you want both at same indices just `shift`the labels by one before passing in the generator.