# Time Series prediction for python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am working on a code which looks like below:

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df['fraction'] = df ['number'] / df['year_total']
df.fraction = df.fraction.round(4)
df
```

> Gives output as

[image]

```
programming_lang = ["r", "python", "c#", "java", "JavaScript", "php", "c++", "ruby", "Selenium"]

yearly_top = df[df['tag'].isin(programming_lang)]
yearly_top
```

> Gives output as below:

```
year, tag, number, year_total, fraction
2008, java, 7473, 58390,0.1280
2008, php, 3111, 58390, 0.0533
2008, Python, 2080, 58390, 0.0356
......
2019, java, 83841, 1085170, 0.0773
2019, php, 61257, 1085170, 0.0564
2019, python, 107348, 1085170, 0.0989
```

It contains top programming language data from 2008 to 2019. I want to use a time series model to predict the `fraction` value for these programming languages for the year 2020, 2021, and 2022. I am very new to this area. Any leads will be helpful

Comment: To predict time series data you could use the tensorflow framework to train a model which will be able to predict the values for the upcoming years. An example of this can be found here: [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series)

Comment: I worked on a similar project recently. I had to predict the EBITDA of a company the next five years  using past data. I used a combination of monte carlo simulation and linear regression. https://github.com/Stamtiniakos/Monte-Carlo-Simulation/blob/master/monte_carlo_simulation.ipynb

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721591/recurrent-neural-networks-for-time-series-with-multiple-variables-tensorflow/58877015#58877015) might help you to reshape your data for RNNs.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using RNN. First, let's create an example dataframe to work with

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'year':range(2008,2020)})
# 0-java, 1-php, 2-python
for ind in range(3): test_df['frac_%i' % ind] = np.random.rand(2020-2008)
test_df = test_df.drop('year',axis=1)
# the array of fractions 
data = test_df.values
```

Before dropping the column `year`, `test_df` looks like

```
    year    frac_0    frac_1    frac_2
0   2008  0.457123  0.780754  0.978396
1   2009  0.578795  0.323664  0.909824
2   2010  0.707996  0.477242  0.948976
3   2011  0.455918  0.627572  0.137039
4   2012  0.272352  0.144968  0.831693
5   2013  0.064729  0.233168  0.554654
6   2014  0.754608  0.570530  0.968355
7   2015  0.435918  0.264335  0.727189
8   2016  0.699624  0.455323  0.237246
9   2017  0.824758  0.995260  0.333113
10  2018  0.597993  0.384319  0.750074
11  2019  0.598657  0.533934  0.072334
```

When using RNN to do time series analysis, the first thing is to cast the task into a supervised regression task, that is we need to create a dataframe in which each row is

`observations of the past year | observation of a year`

Here is a function that can help you achieve this (I learned this function from [this wonderful post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/xgboost-for-time-series-forecasting/))

```
def series_to_supervised(data,n_in,n_out):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols = list()
    for i in range(n_in,0,-1): cols.append(df.shift(i))
    for i in range(0, n_out): cols.append(df.shift(-i))
    agg = pd.concat(cols,axis=1)
    agg.dropna(inplace=True)

    return agg.values
```

With this function we can create the desired dataframe

```
n_in,n_out = 2,1
data = series_to_supervised(test_df,n_in,n_out)
```

`n_in` is the number of past years we want to use to make predictions, and `n_out` is the number of years we want to predict. In this case, we are predicting only one year given the data of the past two years.

Now that we have prepared the data, we can train a RNN model

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Dropout

x, y= data[:,None,:-n_out*3],data[:,n_in*3:]
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.1,random_state=49)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4,name='lstm_0'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2,name='dropout_0'))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
# fit
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=50,verbose=0)
```

With this model, you can predict the fractions of the years 2020, 2021 and 2022 by

```
# predict 2020 with 2018 and 2019
last_two_years = np.hstack((test_df.values[-2],test_df.values[-1]))[None,None,:]
frac_2020 = model.predict(last_two_years)
# predict 2021 with 2019 and 2020
last_two_years = np.hstack((test_df.values[-1],frac_2020.ravel()))[None,None,:]
frac_2021 = model.predict(last_two_years)
# predict 2022 with 2020 and 2021
last_two_years = np.hstack((frac_2020.ravel(),frac_2021.ravel()))[None,None,:]
frac_2022 = model.predict(last_two_years)
```

The full script

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Dropout


def series_to_supervised(data,n_in,n_out):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols = list()
    for i in range(n_in,0,-1): cols.append(df.shift(i))
    for i in range(0, n_out): cols.append(df.shift(-i))
    agg = pd.concat(cols,axis=1)
    agg.dropna(inplace=True)

    return agg.values

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'year':range(2008,2020)})
# 0-java, 1-php, 2-python
for ind in range(3): test_df['frac_%i' % ind] = np.random.rand(2020-2008)
test_df = test_df.drop('year',axis=1)
# the array of fractions 
data = test_df.values
# cast the task as a supevised regression task 
n_in,n_out = 2,1
data = series_to_supervised(test_df,n_in,n_out)
# train test split
x, y= data[:,None,:-n_out*3],data[:,n_in*3:]
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.1,random_state=49)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4,name='lstm_0'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2,name='dropout_0'))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
# fit
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=50,verbose=0)

# predict 2020 with 2018 and 2019
last_two_years = np.hstack((test_df.values[-2],test_df.values[-1]))[None,None,:]
frac_2020 = model.predict(last_two_years)
# predict 2021 with 2019 and 2020
last_two_years = np.hstack((test_df.values[-1],frac_2020.ravel()))[None,None,:]
frac_2021 = model.predict(last_two_years)
# predict 2022 with 2020 and 2021
last_two_years = np.hstack((frac_2020.ravel(),frac_2021.ravel()))[None,None,:]
frac_2022 = model.predict(last_two_years)

print(frac_2020,frac_2021,frac_2022)
```